# how to find out parent web address from where we navigated in a userControl

Tags: 2007, development, asp.net

I have a Web 1 and Web 2, I also have a link of Web 2 in Web 1 using a link button in a SharePoint Site.

Now If I click on Link button situated on Web 1 it takes me to Web 2, I Have a User Control on Web 2, and In this user control, I want URL of Web 1, I am not sure how I will be doing it as i dont have a lot of experience in ASP.NET but i guess its something to do with View State or "SPContext.Current.Web.Properties[]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();

this is what i was looking for, it gives you the address of client yu navigated to current page.